# Joomla - Add an anchor to the link created by JPaginator

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

I need to add an anchor to the links created by the standard Joomla paginator. In some places the website I'm working in has lots of content, and I want that when I click on the paginator, when the page is reloaded to be placed in my list.

So, what can I do to convert from "site.com/index.php?start=3" to "site.com/index.php?start=3#content"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a `pagination.php` file inside your template's `html` folder to override the default output. You can find an example of this file in joomla3's *protostar* template inside `templates/protostar/html/pagination.php` where you can modify the line 180 that reads:

```
return "<li><a title=\"" . $item->text . "\" href=\"" . $item->link . "\" class=\"pagenav\">" . $display . "</a></li>";
```

and modifying it something like so: `$item->link . "#content\"`

More info on [Pagination Links Overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Pagination_Links_Overrides)